# React Native: Getting errors after structuring the project folders

Tags: react-native, expo

I changed my folder structure to something like this

[image]

Now I am getting these errors

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/Animated.js", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

and 

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I changed my package.json main and app.json entry point

```
 "main": "./src/App.tsx",
```

Still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Op here!. Resolved by doing these steps. If anyone facing this issue you can try this if it works for you.

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/Animated.js", which threw an exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
```

For this, I am using react navigation drawer. So I had to make sure if I installed react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

If you are using drawer navigator and you get this error, I suggest you to go through this article.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

and for his error:

```
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I resolved this by adding path of app.tsx(or root component) in package.json and app.json

```
app.json -> "entryPoint": "./src/App.tsx",
package.json -> "main": "./src/App.tsx",
```

and finally, register root component as mentioned in the below link

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Still not working? try running this command

```
expo start --clear
```